# Laplacian in $L^2$

Tags: integration, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $u:\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ (with $\Omega$ a bounded Lipschitz domain) be a function from $H^1(\Omega)$ with $\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)$. Is it true that $\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_1^2}\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_2^2}\in L^2(\Omega)$?

By $\Delta u=f\in L^2(\Omega)$ in the sense of distributions we mean that:

$$\int_{\Omega} u(x)\Delta\phi(x)\ dx=\int_{\Omega} f(x)\phi(x)\ dx,\ \forall\ \phi\in C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$$

So I wonder if there are $f_1,f_2\in L^2(\Omega)$ such that:

$$\int_{\Omega} u(x)\dfrac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x_1^2}(x)\ dx=\int_{\Omega} f_1(x)\phi(x)\ dx\ \text{and}\ \int_{\Omega}u(x)\dfrac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x_2^2}(x)\ dx=\int_{\Omega} f_2(x)\phi(x)\ dx\ \forall\ \phi\in C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$$

???

$\bullet$ I tried to obtain a counterexample for $\Omega=(0,1)\times (0,1)$ by constructing a function $h(x)=\dfrac{2}{3}\sqrt{x^3}$. It has the property that $h\in H^1(0,1)$ but $\dfrac{d^2 h}{dx^2}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ which is not in $L^2(0,1)$. But it's hard to contruct the function $u$ from that.

Comment: Look for $H^2$ regularity to solutions of elliptic equations: the result is not true for general $\Omega$ but for convex $\Omega$ and smooth $\Omega$.

Comment: We can consider $\Omega$ with uniform Lipschitz boundary. I know that if $u$ is in $H^2(\Omega)$ then the question is obvious. Do you have a reference for the situation presented in my question, please?

Comment: I think you mean the book of Grisvard, for example. I came across this problem from the study of elliptic equations and the results stated there are based on Green's identity which is true for $H^2$ functions. And I wonder if this identity holds for $H^1$ functions with laplacian in $L^2$.